# Question about the product of two squared sequences used in a particular step in proof of Cauchy-Schwartz

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm working through the proof of Cauchy-Schwartz in *Real Analysis* by Carothers (page 41 in my copy), and he uses the following fact, which I can't understand the reasoning behind:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n |x_iy_i| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|^2} $$

where $x,y$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Can someone explain why this must be true? My only idea so far has been to combine the two sums into the same $\sqrt{}$. If you do this, I think you might be able to use the fact that if you multiply out all the summands, then you'll get something that contains (among many other terms) all the terms:

$$ |x_1|^2|y_1|^2 + ... + |x_n|^2|y_n|^2$$

but unfortunately this is as far as I've gotten.

Comment: This fact $\textit{is}$ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked my copy. In the previous paragraph, he proved that
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i y_i\right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2}$$
(i.e. with the absolute values outside the sum). I assume you have read and understood that part?

He then points out that the stronger inequality
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i||y_i| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2}$$
also holds and in fact follows from the previous inequality by replacing $x_i$ with $|x_i|$ and $y_i$ with $|y_i|$. To see why this is true, let's carry out the substitution:
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i||y_i|\right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i|^2}$$
Now notice that the outermost absolute values on the left side are redundant (because the summands are now nonnegative). Also notice that $|x_i|^2 = x_i^2$ and $|y_i|^2 = y_i^2$. Thus we can simplify to obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i||y_i| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2}$$

---

To summarize, we have the chain of inequalities 
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i y_i\right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i||y_i| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2}$$
The first inequality in this chain is simply the triangle inequality, and the second is the apparently stronger form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality derived above.

Answer (score 1):

You can find multiple proofs of Cauchy Schwartz inequality over the internet. This answer is related to your approach to see why this inequality must be true. Observe that $$(a_1^2+a_2^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2)=a_1^2 b_1^2 + a_2^2 b_2^2 + a_1^2b_2^2+a_2^2b_1^2 = (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2)^2+(a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1)^2.$$
Since $(a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1)^2 \ge 0$, $$(a_1^2+a_2^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2)= (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2)^2 +(a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1)^2 \ge (a_1b_1 + a_2b_2)^2.$$
In general, we have
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i^2\right) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i b_i\right)^2 + \sum_{i,j} \left(a_i b_j-b_ja_i\right)^2.$$
This identity is also known as [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity). Using the above-mentioned relationship, it is easy to observe that
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i^2\right) \ge \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i b_i\right)^2 .$$